# How to select NULL if there are no data and display the data if it exist?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I'd like to do a select AS NULL from MySQL db. This is the select query:

```
function get_new()
{
    $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%d/%m-%Y') AS date_created, NULL AS name, NULL AS address, NULL AS status FROM t_penomoran";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->row();

    return $result;
}
```

This is the controller

```
public function add()
{
    $id         = 0;
    $master     = $this->MPenomoran->get_new();

    $data = array (
        'titlepage'     => APP_TITLEPAGE,
        'titleapp'      => 'Penomoran',
        'userid'        => $this->session->userdata('nip'),
        'id'            => $id,
        'record'        => $master,
        'error'         => '',
        'complete'      => 'true',
        'loadmethod'    => 'add',
        'contentpage'   => 'penomoran/detail');

    $this->load->view('shared/master_app', $data);
}
```

And when I use this on the view:

```
<?php echo $record->name; ?>
```

I kepp getting `Trying to get property of non-object error`. How to solve this?

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_penomoran` (
`nomor` int(50) NOT NULL,
`date_created` date DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`jenis_pekerjaan` text,
`nominal` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`pic` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`keterangan` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Comment: Do you have check value of `$record` (e.g: var_dump() )?

Comment: it's `NULL`. It should be `date, NULL, NULL, NULL` right??

Comment: The table `t_penomoran` is empty (0 rows)? If table is empty, the query result = null is normally.

Comment: Yes. It should be returned 1 new row (Date, NULL, NULL, NULL).

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here please show an example of the output you want

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object error` because query is **failing**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'd like to select from a table. IF the table has no data. It gives me one row result consist of `todays date, NULL, NULL, NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table is empty (0 rows), the query result = null is normally.

And you want to show row data when row ID x is exists, you should be select column, not `select NULL AS column`, because if row data is exists, all column value is null forever.

So, change code to SQL do not select null, and when query result is empty, return a default sets, like this:

```
function get_data( $id )
{
    $query = "SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%d/%m-%Y') AS date_created,
            `name`,
            `address`,
            `status`
        FROM `t_penomoran`
        WHERE `nomor` = '{$id}'";

    $result = $this->db->query($query)->row();

    if ( empty($result) ) {
        $result = (object)[
            'date_created' => date('d/m-Y'),
            'name' => null,
            'address' => null,
            'status' => null,
        ];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: well, actually use that function for the purpose of edit too. If the vale of ID x is exist, show the data of ID x instead of the NULL rows

Comment: @ashura91 Updated answer. And i seen your table structure now, your table not have column 'ID' or any primary column, you need set it.

Comment: You can check like this also `if($result->num_rows() > 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql if-else in your select query like -

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%d/%m-%Y') AS date_created, 
    IF(name IS NULL, '', name) AS name, 
    IF(address IS NULL, '', address) AS address, 
    IF(status IS NULL, '', status) AS status 
FROM t_penomoran
```

I executed the query and it gives the result as mentioned below without any error -

```
date_created | name | address | status
13/02-2017   |      |         | 1
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it gives error. and still `NULL` not `DATE, NULL, NULL, NULL`

Comment: Are you inserted null at place of the column if empty values are being inserted, can u share your table structure?

Comment: yes. the table allowed NULL values if no data is inserted

Comment: I've added the table structure.

Comment: please see the updated one. what you are expected in output? i dont find any error in query.

Answer (score 1):

how about if you just do it like this...

`if (empty($record->name))
{
echo "Name";
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the NULL as field, it is:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%d/%m-%Y') AS date_created, NULL AS name, NULL AS address, AS status FROM t_penomoran";

address, AS status
```

You have nothing between the , and the AS here.

Comment: that's typo.it's `NULL AS Status`

Comment: If that typo was in your code, it will give you the exact error you're showing. A single NULL usually indicates there's an error in the SQL and no result set at all is being returned. Can you provide the actual line of code being executed? Copy/Paste. The new line provided after fixing the typo would only fail if the table name is wrong.

Comment: I have check the query and no typo in the query.