# PHP date is always being returned as 01 January 1970 instead of null

Tags: php

[The date returned part should be null until i updated it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxvgy.jpg)

```
<td width="50" align="center"><?php echo $returneddate; ?></td>
```

I have changed my date to strtotime but it is executing it to 01-01-1970 everytime. It is supposed to be null until i updated the date. I have googled so many solutions but couldnt get a thing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simply check it first, then choose the display method.

Comment: You need to check for null value -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196003/how-to-select-null-if-there-are-no-data-and-display-the-data-if-it-exist/42196052#42196052

Comment: share your code ?

Comment: also share `$returneddate` value `echo $returneddate;` ?

Comment: <?php $returneddate = $row_admin_equipment_booking_list['returned_date'];$returneddate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($returneddate));?>      

<td width="50" align="center"><?php echo $returneddate; ?></td>

Comment: what is value of `$returneddate` ?

Comment: what stored in `$row_admin_equipment_booking_list['returned_date']` ?

Comment: it stored a returning date that should be updated later by the admin. it should be null until the admin updated the returning date.

Comment: Do you have checked table data or column default value isn't null?

Comment: you need to change column structure as nullable and in view check null and display blank or whatever you want

Comment: @PPACAS post your code where you converted your date to strtotime

Answer (score 0):

check if there is value in database then do date formatting:

```
$display_date = ($db_date)?date('d-m-y',strtotime($db_date)):'';
```